# Why does PHPPGAdmin gives insert error when the command line does not?

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I'm trying to do an insert into PHPPGadmin into one of my tables:

```
INSERT INTO teachers (first_name,last_name,school,hire_date,salary) VALUES ('Ron','Buckby','F.D. Roosevelt School','04-17-1979',34900);
```

And I get an error back:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (INSERT INTO teachers (first_n...
                                              ^
In statement:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (INSERT INTO teachers (first_name,last_name,school,hire_date,salary) VALUES ('Ron','Buckby','F.D. Roosevelt School','04-17-1979',34900)) AS sub
```

However if I do the same exact insert on the command line it works:

```
analysis=# INSERT INTO teachers (first_name,last_name,school,hire_date,salary) VALUES ('Ron','Buckby','F.D. Roosevelt School','04-17-1979',34900);
INSERT 0 1
```

I can then do a select on the data:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE first_name ilike 'ron' AND last_name ilike 'buckby';
 id | first_name | last_name |        school         | hire_date  | salary
----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------+--------
 16 | Ron        | Buckby    | F.D. Roosevelt School | 1979-04-17 |  34900
(1 row)
```

Why does this insert fail only when I use PHPPGAdmin?

Comment: Where does the "SELECT count(*) FROM "-part come from?

Comment: Got me! All I did was the insert.